# How to use PartialView to bind Data in webgrid on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one DropDownlist and Webgrid.When I load Page all Datas where Bind then i need to bind Data in Webgrid depending upon DropDownlist change.How to i do this.

My Code Is:

`Script:`

It will call the Controller Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Cust_Id").change(function () {
          firstDDLValue = $("#Cust_Id").val();    
          $.post(
            '@Url.Action("SelectCustomerByID", "Admin")', 
            { 
                secondValue: firstDDLValue 
            }, 
            function (ReceiptList) {
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`Controller Code:`

```
public ActionResult SelectCustomerByID(Receipt model,string secondValue)
{
    int CustID = 0;
    if (secondValue != "")
    {
        CustID = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue);
    }
    ObservableCollection<Receipt> ReceiptList = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();
    Receipt Receipt = new Models.Receipt();
    model.ReceiptList = Receipt.GetReceiptListByCustID(CustID);
    return View(model.ReceiptList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a `PartialView` in your action:

```
return PartialView(model.ReceiptList);
```

This only works if you have a view called `SelectCustomerByID`. If you have a view with another name you can specify that in an overload:

```
return PartialView("_NameOfPartialView", model.ReceiptList);
```

Then in your `success` function of `$.post()`:

```
function (ReceiptList) {
    // ReceiptList will contain the html of the grid.
    $('#id-of-datagrid').html(ReceiptList);
}
```

Note: I think you have to remove the `Receipt model` parameter from `SelectCustomerByID`.

Comment: sir I tried to set ID for WEBGRID  but unable to set id in it..how to set ID for WEBGRID..

Comment: @PraveenS wrap the web-grid in a div with an id: `<div id="web-grid"></div>`. Then you can use `$('#web-grid')`.

Comment: @PraveenS what does `ReceiptList` return?

Comment: ReceiptList having database value but it doesn't return back to View page that is an problem sir

Comment: Well that is what I meant basically.

Comment: @PraveenS I know, but I assumed you had a view called `SelectCustomerByID`. ASP.NET MVC searches for a view with the same name as the action by convention.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38766/discussion-between-praveen-s-and-henk-mollema)

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for this I just modified my `Script` and Use `ParitalView` to bind data in gird
My Solution Code is:

`Script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#Cust_Id").change(function () {
 firstDDLValue = $("#Cust_Id").val();
 $.get('@Url.Action("SelectCustomerByID", "Admin")', { secondValue: firstDDLValue }, function (ReceiptList) {
  $('#gridContent').html(ReceiptList);
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

i create new _Recepitgrid.cshtml as `PartialView` and write the code for Webgrid as Same as in the main view.

`Controller`

```
public ActionResult SelectCustomerByID(Receipt model, string secondValue)
{
 int CustID = 0;
 if (secondValue != "")
 CustID = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue);
 ObservableCollection<Receipt> ReceiptList = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();
 Receipt Receipt = new Models.Receipt();
 ReceiptList = Receipt.GetReceiptListByCustID(CustID);
 return PartialView("_Recepitgrid", ReceiptList);
}
```

Now it will works fine..